# AJAX POST request in Codeigniter works only the first time

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter project in which a view makes an ajax post request. I have CSRF protection enabled but the request only succeeds the first time. The next time it tries to use the same csrf token but the token in the cookie changes which returns a forbidden error.

One way I found was to turn off `csrf_regenerate` in `config.php`. But won't that almost nullify csrf protection? Is there a way to turn off regeneration for a single page.

Apart from turning of regeneration, is there a way to tackle this keeping the same security level.

I don't want to use GET request

**Update:** Code I am using

```
var d = {'data':$("#data").text(),"<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>":"<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>"};

$.ajax({
        url:"controller/function/",
        type:"POST",
        data: d,
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
        }

     });
```

Comment: please let me know your code.

Comment: Just read the CSRF Cookie and send it via ajax.